# git stash not working in an IntelliJ PowerShell, why is that?

Tags: git, powershell, intellij-idea, pycharm

I installed git using scoop and generally it seems to be working fine, but I run into an odd situation. When I try to stash changes in a PowerShell console inside IntelliJ (PyCharm actually), I get this error:

```
> git stash
fatal: could not exec C:/Users/pupeno/scoop/apps/git/current/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git-legacy-stash: No such file or directory
```

Indeed that file doesn't exist; but running git stash on a standalone PowerShell works. Any idea why this might be?

The way I configure PowerShell to be my terminal is like this:

[image]

and this is what the error looks like:

[image]

Comment: `When I try to stash changes in a PowerShell console inside IntelliJ` how did you open the ps console?

Comment: @Andrey: I set the terminal in IntelliJ to be powershell.exe and then open a Terminal. I'll add this detail to the question.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can run stash commands in standalone cmd but not in PyCharm. Have you already found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Although the error output the above location the file itself should be under the git installation folder:

```
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core
```

> but running git stash on a standalone PowerShell works. Any idea why this might be?

The problem is likely due to the fact that there are spaces in the folder name.
Windows knows how to handle it well.

To verify that this is indeed the problem install git portable version, update your configuration and check to see if there is an error.

Git Portable: https://github.com/sheabunge/GitPortable/

Comment: That's not where Git is installed, it's in `C:/Users/pupeno/scoop/apps/git/current/`. I installed it using scoop. I don't think there are spaces in the path, but maybe I'm missing something.